# Proof by induction question about fuel depots

Tags: induction

> You are asked to drive a lunar rover around the moon (which is just a circle in this
>   question). There are (finitely many) fuel depots on the way, with the total amount of
>   fuel stored in them enough to get around the moon exactly once. Show that there exists
>   a depot from which you can start driving and travel the whole way around the moon,
>   picking up fuel at each depot as you pass, without running out of fuel between depots.

Can I have a hint for this? I've tried induction but I'm having trouble with the induction step.

Comment: Induction is of little use (and gives little insight) here, though it *is* possible ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start anywhere and assume you have some unspecified sufficient (i.e. you will never run out of fuel along the trip) amount $x$ of fuel in the tank initially. As you refill during the trip exactly as much as you consume, you will end up with the same amount $x$ of fuel after the full round. During the trip, the fuel continuously decreases, except at the depots, where it suddenly increases. Let $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ be the amounts of fuel in your tank when arriving at the $n$ depots. By assumption, $x$ was large enough so that all $x_i$ are $\ge 0$. Among all suitable choices of $x$, there is one we cannot go below: For some $x$, at least one of the $x_i$ will become $=0$. Now what if we start at this (or one of these, if there are several) depot with empty tank, fill from the depot and start?

Comment: Thanks, I think I've got it now, it's hard to explain in words though.